# The command '/bin/sh returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: docker

When I try to install a bin file manually inside a ubuntu Docker container it works perfectly,

```
./MyBinfile.bin
```

but when I try it from my Dockerfile I always get the error :
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x /tmp/snapcenter_linux_host_plugin.bin && ./tmp/MyBinFile.bin' returned a non-zero code: 1

My Dockerfile looks like :

```
    FROM debian:jessie

    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk
    ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
    RUN echo $JAVA_HOME

    COPY MyBinFile.bin /tmp/MyBinFile.bin
    RUN chmod +x /tmp/MyBinFile.bin && ./tmp/MyBinFile.bin
```

Can anyone help me in this case?

Comment: Your cwd is likely not /tmp, so try executing it as absolute path instead.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi: sorry that was a typo, 
I fixed my docker file in the question.

Comment: What's in MyBinFile.bin? Did you edit this file from a Windows machine?

Answer (score 7):

You copied MyBinFile.bin to /tmp/MyBinFile.bin. Those are not the same file. If you need to run it use absolute path for the file that has executable attribute on it. So your last line should be:

```
RUN chmod +x /tmp/MyBinFile.bin && /tmp/MyBinFile.bin
```

'.' (dot) represents your current current working directory. It's recommended to always use absolute paths if you're unsure what is your cwd.

**EDIT**

Running your Dockerfile produces the following output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.584 kB
Step 1/6 : FROM debian:jessie
 ---> 8cedef9d7368
Step 2/6 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1a0005923f41
Step 3/6 : ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5651d50b519e
Step 4/6 : RUN echo $JAVA_HOME
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 96655235a2cf
Step 5/6 : COPY MyBinFile.bin /tmp/MyBinFile.bin
 ---> 60c79aaf5aca
Removing intermediate container cd729c315e9b
Step 6/6 : RUN chmod +x /tmp/MyBinFile.bin && /tmp/MyBinFile.bin
 ---> Running in 5db126cbd24c
/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/MyBinFile.bin: Text file busy
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x /tmp/MyBinFile.bin && 
/tmp/MyBinFile.bin' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

But if I separate your last step into two different steps:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
RUN echo $JAVA_HOME

COPY MyBinFile.bin /tmp/MyBinFile.bin
RUN chmod +x /tmp/MyBinFile.bin
RUN /tmp/MyBinFile.bin
```

then it executes OK.

Comment: I still get the same 
The command '/bin/sh -c chmod +x /tmp/MyBinFile.bin && /tmp/MyBinFile.bin' returned a non-zero code: 1

After trying your solution.

Answer (score 3):

I had a close similar issue when running NextJs inside Docker. Here is how I solved the issue::

Note:: This solution will also solve the `EACCES error...Permission denied` when accessing files inside the dockerized app e.g. route pages.

I added `root` user immediately before the command to change ownership then later switched back to run the rest of the commands together with container with `non-root` user i.e. `node` user from base alpine image.

```golang
# The "./" is the working directory e.g. /usr/app
USER root
RUN chmod a+w ./ -R

# Later switch back to run rest of commands and container as node non-root user 
USER node
```